# node / express - render page before db callback?

Tags: node.js, express

Full disclosure: I'm very new to the totally asynchronous model.

In my application there are a number of instances where information needs to be committed to the db, but the application can continue on without knowing the result. Is it acceptable to render a page before waiting for a db write to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.jsonp({
    message: 'Hello World!'
  });
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    i++;
  }
});
```

When a user visits '/', he will see the result immediately. But if there is only one node instance is running, when the other user visits '/', he won't receive any response as the only instance is under a infinite loop.

If you have a lot of heavy work to do(for example, CPU-bound works), it's much better to use a message queue such as MSMQ and AMQP instead of having all the works done in the node instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. But how would you notify the user of an error if something did go wrong? Unless you're doing sockets or ajax or something, requests are the standard way.

Comment: For situations where the user has no need to know (i.e. various forms of logging). If an error occurs, it's handled on the server.